# How to define md-color/color directly to the HTML element in angular material2

Tags: angular-material2

Is there any way to define color/background color directly to the HTML element in material2?
Same as that of angular material (previous version):

```
<label md-colors="{background: 'purple-600'}">
<p md-colors="{color: 'Grey-500'}">
```